# I want to include into a html file using thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

**I have a header.html like this:**
I have set fragment for  name "nav"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" th:fragment="nav">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DongPoppa</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to replace(include) this nav in header.html into home.html using Thymeleaf
like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="header::nav">123 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work!
(header.html and home.html is in the same folder) (webapp/user/views/..)

Comment: You mean you want to include `header.html` into `home.html` ?

Comment: yes. i want to include "nav" from header.html into home.html

Comment: Your implementation looks fine. Check your file locations, if you are using spring boot try using files placed into templates folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way into `home.html`:

```html
<div th:replace="header :: header"></div>
```

Comment: I had try it before and just try it again. It seen not work for me.
btw, header is my html name. in header.html I just have ```<nav>```

Comment: @DongPoppa can you add project hierarchy of html files